# Stripe – "Invalid timestamp: can be no more than five years in the future"

Tags: node.js, datetime, stripe-payments

I'm using the Node.js Stripe package, and I want to add a new subscription to a customer which expires in 30 seconds. Here is my code:

```
var toCreate = {
  customer: 'customer_id',
  items: [{
    plan: 'plan_id'
  }],
  coupon: 'coupon_code',
}
stripe.customers.create({xyz: 'This will give an error with the server time in the header'}).then(success => {},
  error => {
    var seconds = 30;
    toCreate.trial_end = new Date(error.raw.headers.date).getTime() + (seconds * 1000);
    console.log('End time', toCreate.trial_end);
    return stripe.subscriptions.create(toCreate).then(successful => {
      console.log(successful)
    }, error => {
      console.log(error)
    })
  })
```

The code purposely creates an error to get the accurate server time, and then makes the actual `stripe.subscriptions.create` call.

When I call `stripe.subscriptions.create`, Stripe is giving me this error:

> Invalid timestamp: can be no more than five years in the future

The timestamp that my code gave it in this situation was `1535104976000`.
It included this in the error message headers:

```
date: 'Fri, 24 Aug 2018 10:02:27 GMT'
```

Converted to an epoch, that is `1535104947000`.

So, my time is definitely not 5 years ahead of theirs! What on Earth is going on?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Seems it's timestamp related. PHP timestamp is in seconds while JavaScript timestamp is in miliseconds.
Have you tried to divide by 1000?

Comment: Bold would be great, but just being present somewhere would be nice. Sometimes the division gives a float, but it must be an int. So, `Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000 + seconds)`. Another thing is I think the minimum is 1 minute. Even specifying 30 seconds, it seems to last about a minute